# Task Sequence .vbs execution

Tags: vbscript, sccm

I'm in the midst of developing a task sequence to deploy a new Windows 7 64bit image to a couple of computers. I'm fairly new to SCCM and newer still to maintaining a 64bit OS.

The problem I'm having is with vbs script deployments. Within this task sequence, I have two instances of copying from a network share to the local machines' `C:\Windows\System32\` folder and one instance of needing to write to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\\*SOME SOFTWARE*`.

When these scripts are executed by the local machine during the Task Sequence, they are ran by cscript.exe *32. This is a problem because my copied files wind up in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`and my reg keys are written to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\`.

I've been able to use Group Policy startup scripts as a work around, but I would like the Task Sequence to be self contained. My question is: How can I force a 64 bit execution of these scripts during my Task Sequence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a check box within the task sequence that states "Disable 64-bit file system redirection.  This should resolve your issues. More information: [Technet Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2009/06/03/osd-task-sequence-a-script-may-fail-without-error-when-deploying-a-64-bit-os.aspx)